# Node parse data from one view to another

Tags: node.js, parsing, handlebars.js

Let's say I have one view

### users.handlebars

```
{{#each users}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{this.id}}</td>
                <td>{{this.profile.firstname}}</td>
                <td>{{this.profile.lastname}}</td>
                <td>{{this.profile.location}}</td>
                <td>{{this.email}}</td>
                <td>{{this.profile.status}}</td>
                <td><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
                <a class="user-ban-btn" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="user-delete-btn" href="javascript:void(0)"> // THIS IS DELETE BUTTTON
                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
```

And another

### main.handlebars

```
<div class="modal-box" id="user-delete-modal">
        <div class="modal-box-message">
            <p>Are you sure u want to delete this user?</p>
            <a href="delete/{{HERE I NEED ID OF USER TO DELETE}}">YES</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="user-delete-btn">NO</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In first view, I click on button delete user but I need to parse data from this view to the second view where I choose YES or NO because yes have a link with ID parameter `/users/delete/:id` But i don't know to do it.

Note: Main.handlebars is template and users.handlebars is inserted into this template and that modal box is opened just with javascript there is no page refresh.

I will be thankful for any idea how to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `onClick="get_user_id(this.id)"` to `a` element.
And then taking it with javascript.